# maven - create archive of generated jar files

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am currently building out some projects using an aggregate pom. It calls out some parent poms that build out the artifacts.

The artifacts build out ok.

What I would like is to capture the generated jar files and place them into a directory as they are created build after build, version after version.

Possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, on mobile, not enough patience on it to give a full answer: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Slanec - I tried the assembly plugin using the goal "mvn assembly:assembly" which worked up to a point. I then noticed on the site that this goal was being deprecated so slashed that idea. I couldn't find a decent example that allowed me to do something similar with the "mvn assembly:single" goal

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about why you want to achieve this, it's hard to recommend a solution.

A `mvn clean install` will install all the artifacts into your local repository, but assuming you want a more custom directory layout - you could use the maven-antrun-plugin and use ant to arrange the relevant files.

If you're happy with the default repository layout, you could also configure the repository settings for the project to deploy your plugin into a specific filesystem location (which would be dedicated to this particular project).

Alternatively, you could use the wagon plugin to do the deployment: 
http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/deploying-in-file-system-using-maven

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the wagon plugin - it's new on me & may come in useful

Answer (score 0):

im using a .bat file that runs

```
cd dir
mvn clean install
copy dir\*.jar %LIFERAY_TOMCAT_HOME%"\..\deploy
```

what do you think? would that suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks cristianhh, I will use your suggestion to get something running/working in the short term. (Am thinking to use the exec plugin to auto run after successful execution of the compile phase).